# How to detect when a user has submitted a $_FILE for upload then process request?

Tags: php, file, upload, image-uploading

Hi we planning on allowing our users to upload a cover photo and profile photo on the same page but we need to detect when they are submitting the files to us. The code that we already have can be seen below. We have tried the if(isset and if(exist but that doesn't seem to do anything.

```
if($_POST['account_view'] === 'design') {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['cover'])) {
        if(isset($_FILES['cover']['name']) === true) {
            if(empty($_FILES['cover']['name']) === true) {
                    $errors[] = 'Please select a file to use as your cover photo.';
            } else {
            $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

                $file_name = $_FILES['cover']['name'];
                $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
                $file_temp = $_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'];

                if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
                    change_cover_image($session_user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn);
                    header("Location: $url/user/settings/?success&design");
                } else {
                    $allowed_file_types_r = implode(', ', $allowed);
                    $errors[] = "You can\'t use this file type as your cover photo, but you can use these file types $allowed_file_types_r.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile']['name'])) {
        if(isset($_FILES['profile']) === true) {
            if(empty($_FILES['profile']['name']) === true) {
                $errors[] = 'Please select a file to use as your profile photo.';
            } else {
                $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

                $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
                $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
                $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];

                if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
                    change_profile_image($session_user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn);
                    header("Location: $url/user/settings/?success&design");
                } else {
                    $allowed_file_types_r = implode(', ', $allowed);
                    $errors[] = "You can\'t use this file type as your profile photo, but you can use these file types $allowed_file_types_r.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ($_FILES['profile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { file was uploaded }`

Comment: @MarcB could you please enter your response as an answer, so I can mark it as a good answer. Also thanks because it worked!